# http request from flutter to a node.js server

Tags: node.js, flutter, http, post

I wrote this in index.js:

```
const rules = [
  [['check engine light is on', 'car wont start'], 'Dead battery'],
  [['car wont start', 'clicking sound'], 'Bad starter motor'],
  [['car wont start', 'no sound'], 'Bad battery connection'],
  [['car stalls or dies while driving', 'car wont restart'], 'Faulty alternator']}


// Working memory and agenda
let working_memory = [];
let agenda = [];

// Inference engine
function backward_chaining(symptoms) {
  working_memory = working_memory.concat(symptoms);
  agenda = agenda.concat(symptoms);

  let diagnosis_made = false; // flag to check if a diagnosis has been made

  while (agenda.length) {
    const symptom = agenda.pop();

    for (const rule of rules) {
      if (rule[0].includes(symptom)) {
        const premise = rule[0].filter(s => s !== symptom);

        if (premise.every(p => working_memory.includes(p))) {
          working_memory.push(rule[1]);
          agenda.push(rule[1]);

          // If a rule was fired, a diagnosis has been made
          diagnosis_made = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (!diagnosis_made) { // if no diagnosis was made, return "No diagnosis found"
    return "No diagnosis found";
  }

  const diagnosis = working_memory[working_memory.length - 1];
  return diagnosis;
}


app.use(express.json());

// Endpoint
app.post('/infer', (req, res) => {
  const symptoms = req.body.symptoms;
  const diagnosis = backward_chaining(symptoms);
  res.json({ diagnosis: diagnosis });
});


const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}...`));
```

and here is my flutter code:

```
class _InferencePageState extends State<InferencePage> {
  final TextEditingController _symptomsController = TextEditingController();
  String _solution = '';

  Future<void> _submitSymptoms() async {
    final String apiUrl = 'http://IputMyIpAddressHere:3000/infer';
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(apiUrl),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: jsonEncode(
        <String, dynamic>{'symptoms': _symptomsController.text.split(',')},
      ),
    );
    timeout:
    Duration(seconds: 20);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        _solution = responseData['diagnosis'] ?? 'No solution found.';
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _solution = 'Error: ${response.statusCode}';
      });
    }
  }
```

when I test my api in thunder client, it works fine, but when I send a post request to it through a flutter app, I always get No diagnosis found, until I test it, so if i test it in thunder client then immediately send the same request from my flutter page, I get a response, then if I restart the server and resend the request I get the No diagnosis response again, so it looks like the testing is creating some cache that flutter uses to respond, how can I solve this to get a response directly without the need to test it

I tried to add a timeout but did not work, (note that the url that flutter is sending is the machine ip address that is hosting the server because localhost in flutter didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Can you share piece of code used to call your API in flutter?

Please note that, you can not use localhost from your mobile app, emulator, simulator. You have to use IP to run application to access server run locally.

Comment: I added it, I'd be thankful if you can help !

Comment: First, make sure that you used correct IP by opening this url from your browser. http://IputMyIpAddressHere:3000/infer

Comment: Also, since its http non secure endpoint, you have to make sure to enabled required configuration. For example for Android use -> usesCleartextTraffic